# Assigning a Char Value to a Vector Element. C++

Tags: c++, vector

Lets say you have a 4 choices

```
(a) Snake
(b) Bird
(C) Fish
(D) Turtle
```

Each of the choices being part of `vector<string> pet;`.

My question is, how do I assign the letter value of lets say `(a)` to `Snake`. So when the user is presented with the above output, they just type `a` and click enter to select whatever is in that choice (in the example above, that would be `Snake`). How would you output your choices so it looks like the above?

Comment: You need to output Snake-Bird-Fish-Turtle when user types a-d, am I right?

Comment: @АлександрКушниренко no, when the user enters say a, it should output that choice only, not all four.

Comment: Do you need to use exactly std::vector? Like, as I understand, you just need 4-element array, which will hold these Snake-Turtle and just output them.

Comment: Do you know what a switch is? The *output* of a known string ("(a) Snake (b) Bird (C) Fish (D) Turtle") should not pose an insurmountable problem.

Comment: On most C++ implementations you could `index = choice - 'a';` to get an index into a `std::vector<std::string>`. You'll have to test that the target uses a sane character encoding (Contiguous and ascending order), but these days you'll be hard pressed to find a system that doesn't comply.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a `std::map` to create a mapping between a choice letter and an animal string. It makes it easier to query the map with a key for the associated value, here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {

    // making a mapping between two strings, a letter and animal
    std::map<std::string, std::string> pet = {{"a", "Snake"},
                                              {"b", "Bird"},
                                              {"c", "Fish"},
                                              {"d", "Turtle"}};
    // dialogue
    std::cout << "Select a pet: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(a) " << pet.at("a") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(b) " << pet.at("b") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(c) " << pet.at("c") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(d) " << pet.at("d") << std::endl;

    // read input into a string variable
    std::string choice;
    std::cin >> choice;

    // output selected letter mapping to animal
    std::cout << "You selected a " << pet.at(choice) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> Select a pet:
>
> (a) Snake
>
> (b) Bird
>
> (c) Fish
>
> (d) Turtle
>
> **a**
>
> You selected a Snake

Answer (score 1):

You don't need std::vector, because you know the size of an array. You can just initialize it with strings:

```
    array<string, 4> arr = { "Snake", "Bird", "Fish", "Turtle" };
    char x;
    cin >> x;
    cout << arr[x - 'a'];
```

If you need a wrong input checking, you have to add an if-statement before cout.

```
if (x >= 'a' && x <= 'd')
```

Answer (score 0):

First start by defining your container of pets (I'm concerned about the lack of dogs and cats):

```
std::vector<std::string> pets = { "Snake", "Bird", "Fish", "Turtle" };
```

Now we know the possible pets, we can output those:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> pets = { "Snake", "Bird", "Fish", "Turtle" };
    std::cout << "Pick your pet:";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < pets.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << " " << pets[i];
    }
}
```

This gives us

> Pick your pet: Snake Bird Fish Turtle

Which is close. `char` is just an integer, which we can use when printing the pets:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < pets.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << " (" << char('a' + i) << ") " << pets[i];
}
```

We say print `'a' + i` because that will give us `a` for the first element, `b` for the second etc.

Now you can use that same logic when referencing your container <sub>(I've omitted any erorr handling here, but you should ensure that `userChoice` is an appropriate value):</sub>

```
char userChoice;
std::cin >> userChoice;
std::cout << "You chose " << pets[userChoice-'a'];
```

Now if the user enters `d`, we minus `a` from it which gives us 3, which is the last element in the container, and will print

> You chose Turtle

Comment: I'm more concerned about the snake